# -bash: cygrunsrv: command not found

Tags: cygwin

i wanted to run this

"cygrunsrv --install varnishd --path /cygdrive/c/cygwin64/usr/sbin/varnishd.exe"

on windows server 2016 but i am getting.

"-bash: cygrunsrv: command not found. "

Not sure if file is required. But if so please send me the executable as well

Comment: Requests that someone find or provide an executable are out-of-scope here -- see #4 in the "some questions are still off-topic" list at http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

Answer (score 5):

You need to install `cygrunsrv`.  You will find it under the "Admin" category in the Cygwin `setup` utility.

Comment: Relatedly, if you're not running it in the Cygwin-provided terminal you must ensure that `C:\cygwin64\bin` is on your `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: To add to @Iguananaut comment, you can do that by adding at the beginning of the bash script: `export PATH="$PATH:/cygdrive/c/tools/cygwin/bin"` (you may have to adapt the path in the future).